# regular expression pattern annotation validation java

Tags: validation

I have created a @url constraint validation and provided regex. Above it I have annotated @pattern. So, whenever in my bean I am entering value in field url, the url is getting validated

Currently i have a regex which is validating this url. "http://www.google.com".

My new requirement is it should validate only "www.google.com"
I can just change the regex and it will work. but the problem is there are 2 different scenarios
1.In one i need to validate "http://www.google.com"
2.In second i need to validate this "www.google.com"

So, i cannot change the regex. Can anyone please help how can I resolve this? If i need to use custom validator instead of hibernate validator, then how can i achieve this?

I have tried to create
1.custom validator and in isvalid method i am validating the url without @Pattern
2.I have tried @Pattern by changing my regex to just validate domain and path and skip protocol http

Comment: Make the protocol part of your regex optional: `(https?://)?...`

Comment: Protocol is already part of regex optional. I need 2 regex, one with protocol and one without protocol to get executed for different class.